# mysql sub query reference outer table

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I am trying to use the outer table in a sub query select. While I can hardcode the value and get the required results; I really need to use the outer phppos_items table; but cannot figure it out. Below is the simplified query. Is there any way to do this? The reason I am using a sub query as I want to get only one row in the join.

The part I am trying to get the outer table is *XXX*

```
SELECT SUM(trans_current_quantity) as quantity FROM `phppos_items` 
LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_items` ON `phppos_location_items`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` and `phppos_location_items`.`location_id` IN(1)
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM phppos_inventory WHERE trans_date < '2018-05-06 23:59:59' and
trans_items = *XXX* ORDER BY trans_date DESC LIMIT 1) as inventory 
ON `phppos_location_items`.`item_id` = `inventory`.`trans_items`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query, with table aliases making it a bit more readable:

```
SELECT SUM(trans_current_quantity) as quantity
FROM phppos_items i LEFT JOIN
     phppos_location_items li
     ON li.item_id = i.item_id and li.location_id IN (1) LEFT JOIN 
     (SELECT * 
      FROM phppos_inventory inv
      WHERE inv.trans_date < '2018-05-06 23:59:59' and
            trans_items = *XXX*
      ORDER BY trans_date DESC LIMIT 1
     ) inv 
    ON li.item_id = inv.trans_items;
```

I can only interpret `trans_current_quantity` as coming from `phppos_inventory`.  The `LEFT JOIN`s appear to be superfluous as you've written the query.

What you really want is a lateral join.  That doesn't work in MySQL, alas.  Here is the next closest thing:

```
SELECT SUM(inv.trans_current_quantity) as quantity
FROM phppos_items i JOIN
     phppos_location_items li
     ON li.item_id = i.item_id and li.location_id IN (1) JOIN 
     phppos_inventory inv
     ON li.item_id = inv.trans_items
WHERE li.item_id = XXX AND
      inv.trans_date = (SELECT MAX(inv2.trans_date)
                        FROM phppos_inventory inv2
                        WHERE inv2.trans_date < '2018-05-07' and
                              inv2.trans_items = li.item_id
                       );
```

I also fixed the date comparison by adding a second.  If that's not right, you can fix it, but the query is more readable.

Comment: Do you mean WHERE li.item_id = i.item_id?

Comment: @ChrisMuench . . . The references in the subquery should be to `inv2`.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to replace *XXX* with the primary key to phppos_items (i.e. item_id), you probably just need to alias the table in the outer query and reference it by the alias in the subquery. If trans_items references something other than the Primary Key (or if item_id) is not the Primary Key, then I'll need more information to help...

```
SELECT SUM(trans_current_quantity) as quantity FROM `phppos_items` AS items1
LEFT JOIN `phppos_location_items` ON `phppos_location_items`.`item_id` = `phppos_items`.`item_id` and `phppos_location_items`.`location_id` IN(1)
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM phppos_inventory WHERE trans_date < '2018-05-06 23:59:59' and trans_items = items1.item_id ORDER BY trans_date DESC LIMIT 1) as inventory 
     ON `phppos_location_items`.`item_id` = `inventory`.`trans_items`
```

Comment: I get error #1054 - Unknown column 'items1.item_id' in 'where clause'